# right side bar not display

Tags: layout, template, design

I want to display products in registration side bar.
i have added reference to customer.xml.

```
 <customer_account_index translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Dashboard</label>
         <reference name="right">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="catalog/product/list/featured.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer_account_dashboard" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml">
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_hello" name="customer_account_dashboard_hello" as="hello" template="customer/account/dashboard/hello.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top" />
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_newsletter" name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" as="newsletter" template="customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml"/>
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="customer/account/dashboard/address.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>

    </customer_account_index>
```

but side bar is not display.

Comment: Could you please check in which folder you have changed the customer.xml file?  ie theme / base / default folder. Magento took theme folder as the first priority.   just  and  remove your reference name = right and confirm the right side bar appears or not.

Comment: Where are you trying to add this? On the page where a customer creates an account or the my accounts pages?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it won't display; did you notice:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

This template will not render the right column. You need to change the template to **page/3columns.phtml**.

However, you should not do any of this in *`customer.xml`*. Your module should specify its own update file, and then you can do both in there:

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="catalog/product/list/featured.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

Comment: Surely page/2columns-RIGHT.phtml will render the right column just like 3columns.phtml would?

Comment: I assume OP still wants the left column as well.